The support of derivatives of the extension operator in Sovolev spaces
The Sobolev extension theorem states that for a given $\Omega$ bounded domain and $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ there exists $E(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that:

$E(u) = u$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$
$\text{supp}(E(u)) \subset V$, where $\Omega \subset \subset V$.

My doubt concerns in item $2)$. Is it true that $\text{supp}(\frac{\partial E(u)}{\partial x_i}) \subset V$ in such a way that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla E(u)| dx = \int_{V} |\nabla E(u)| dx  ?
$$
This follows from the proof of Extension Theorem? If this is not true, is there any additional hypothesis on $u$ for which above identity would be true?

It follows from the definition of derivative and support. Think about derivative in terms of lim of finite difference.

If $\phi\in C^k_{\text{comp}}(\Omega)$ then $\mathrm D^\alpha\phi\in C^0_{\text{comp}}(\Omega)$ for any multi-index $|\alpha|\leq k$.
